# Help to understand: "and for others to do so on behalf of his targets" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-structure

> In trying to find a way to excuse her father, Brennan-Jobs is following a long line of people, all of whom are much more culpable than her for his behavior. Generally, the only way to get a bully to back off is to stand up to him and **for others to do so on behalf of his targets**; in Jobs' case, too few people did.

I am not sure how to parse the sentence correctly: "*the only way to get a bully to back off is to stand up to him and for others to do so on behalf of his targets*".

I can probably get the meaning of the sentence. From the grammar standpoint, what's **and for others to do so on behalf of his targets** doing?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/memoir-steve-jobs-apos-daughter-133000491.html).

Comment: It would seem that in the author's view there is only one way to stop a bully, and it involves a two-pronged effort: the target must stand up to him and others must also stand up to him on the target's behalf.  Either that, or the author should have written **ways** instead of **way** and **or** instead of **and**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help (my explanations are in bold):

> the only way to get a bully to back off is to stand up to him and for others **(those who are not the bully's targets)** to do so **(in other words, to stand up to the bully)** on behalf of his targets

Comment: Most of my difficulty lies in the grammar point. The AND word introduces a juxtaposition here. I am wondering what's the juxtaposition to "for others to do so on behalf of his targets"?

Comment: IMO, "and" is simply a conjunction that joins two clauses, it is similar in meaning to "as well as". I don't think "and" is used for juxtaposition here.

Comment: but "for others to do so on behalf of his targets" is not a complete clause.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. "And" is used to join two similar ideas. Compare it to: The only way to succeed is to work out a plan and to stick to the plan. There's no juxtaposition here. Juxtaposition comes into play when you contrast something (juxtapose it with something). This is an example of juxtaposition: "in movies the protagonist is good and the antagonist is evil".